# List all possible combinations of Ip addresses from given String using Recursive Function

Tags: java, recursion

I have a String `s = "25525511135"`. How can I find all possible list of IP addresses using **recursive function**. I wrote a recursive function for this purpose but it is not working. I cannot understand where I am making a mistake.

```
String s = "25525511135";
int endInd = 1,strInd = 1;
String strNum = s.substring(0,1);

public void restoreIp(String s,List<List<String>> results,List<String> combination,
                          int startIndex, int endIndex,String strNum){

        int num = Integer.parseInt(strNum);
        Integer sumStr = combination.stream().mapToInt(String::length).reduce(0,Integer::sum);

        if (sumStr == s.length() && combination.size() == 4){
            results.add(new ArrayList<>(combination));
            return;
        }

        for (int i = startIndex; i < s.length(); i++){

            if (num >= 0 && num <= 255 && combination.size() < 4){
                combination.add("" + num);
            } else { break; }

            if (sumStr < s.length() && combination.size() > 4){ break; }

            if (sumStr < s.length() && combination.size() == 4){
                if (endIndex < 4) {
                    endIndex = endIndex + 1;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            restoreIp(s,results,combination,i+1,endIndex,s.substring(i,startIndex + endIndex));
            combination.remove(combination.size() - 1);
        }

    }
```

I need to collect all possible lists inside `results` list.
Result should look like below:

```
[
[255,255,11,135]]
[255,255,111,35]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to this problem is as follows:

We only need four parameters for our function, the string to parse, the list of results, the current found combination and the index where to start forming a new number of an ip address.

```
public void restoreIp(String s, List<List<Integer>> results, List<Integer> combination, int startIndex)
```

We start by declaring the stopping conditions, we stop calling the function when the combination has 4 numbers or the string is fully parsed. If the combination has 4 numbers and the string is fully parsed, we add the combination to the list of results, otherwise we just break from the recursive call.

```
if (combination.size() == 4 && startIndex >= s.length()) {
    results.add(combination);
    return;
}

if (combination.size() == 4 || startIndex >= s.length()) {
    return;
}
```

Now the body of the algorithm is to iterate through the string from the `startIndex` and starts forming new numbers, if the number is starting with 0 and has more than two digits (01, 02, ...etc) or greater than 255 we stop iterating because is not a valid ip number otherwise we add the number to the combination and the function call itself.

```
for (int i = startIndex; i < s.length(); i++) {
    String strNumber = s.substring(startIndex, i + 1);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(strNumber);
    if ((s.charAt(startIndex) == '0' && strNumber.length() > 1) || number > 255) {
        return;
    }
    List<Integer> newCombination = new ArrayList<>(combination);
    newCombination.add(number);

    restoreIp(s, results, newCombination, i + 1);
}
```

So the whole code is:

```
public static void restoreIp(String s, List<List<Integer>> results, List<Integer> combination, int startIndex) {
    if (combination.size() == 4 && startIndex >= s.length()) {
        results.add(combination);
        return;
    }
    
    if (combination.size() == 4 || startIndex >= s.length()) {
        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = startIndex; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String strNumber = s.substring(startIndex, i + 1);
        int number = Integer.parseInt(strNumber);
        if ((s.charAt(startIndex) == '0' && strNumber.length() > 1) || number > 255) {
            return;
        }
        List<Integer> newCombination = new ArrayList<>(combination);
        newCombination.add(number);
    
        restoreIp(s, results, newCombination, i + 1);
    }
}
```

Testing with:

```
String str = "17125120120";
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
restoreIp(str, result, new ArrayList<>(), 0);
System.out.println(result);
```

will generate:

```
[[17, 125, 120, 120], [171, 25, 120, 120], [171, 251, 20, 120], [171, 251, 201, 20]]
```

and with: `s = "25525511135"`

```
[[255, 255, 11, 135], [255, 255, 111, 35]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. It is working perfect. I have a question regarding ```newCombination```. Why you are creating each time new List inside for loop. Why we cannot use same ```combination``` list each time?

Comment: @Abdusoli this is because lists in java are passed by reference, so if I pass the same array to say 3 recursive call to restoreIp, the subsequent calls will all update the same list. So we must create a new array each time.